# ngx toastr not working when ivy is enabled in Angular 8

Tags: angular, toast, angular8

ngx toastr library does not work when ivy is enabled in Angular 8. It works when ivy is disabled in the tsconfig.app.json. Then the toasts pop up as normal. ngx-toastr version is "10.0.4".

This is the error I'm getting.

> core.js:7187 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
>   'Document': The tag name provided ('') is not a valid name.

Comment: Basically, I get related issues with other libraries as well, I think you should wait for a more stable version of ivy. you are not the only one.

Comment: yes, putting this question because it should be out there.

Comment: Take a look at this issue (it's not the same, but they're tracking some problems over there): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29564#issuecomment-483662084.

Also, report it on its own repo: https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues